# Error cannot find Column 2 dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]

Tags: asp.net, azure, dataset, datarow

I've been searching for an answer since this code was working fine like an hour ago and I did not make any editting so it turns a little confuse to recognize the error if any of you could help I would appreciate it much. Thanks in advance.

I've checked and there are no errors on the SQL query, as I said it was working fine dr is defined globally as:
DataRow dr = new DataRow();
and MyTable is defined globally also as

```
DataTable MyTable = new DataTable();
```

here's the related code:

```
sentencia = "select * from Facturas" + Session["sociotabla"].ToString() + " where IdFactura = " + Session["idFactura"].ToString();
ds = bd.Consulta(sentencia);
if (ds != null)
{
    dr = MyTable.NewRow();
    dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
    LimpiarControles();
    tbFactura.Text = dr[0].ToString();
    ListItem li;
    for (int i = 0; i < ddlCliente.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        li = ddlCliente.Items[i];
        if (li.Value == dr[2].ToString()) //Error here Cannot find Column 2
        {
            ddlCliente.SelectedIndex = i;
            Session["idCliente"] = dr[2].ToString();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What _error_? Is this the error you got: _"Error cannot find Column 2 dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]"_? Can you be more specific?

Comment: How many columns are present in the table `Facturas" + Session["sociotabla"]`? You try to access the third column of that table in the line `if (li.Value == dr[2].ToString())`. And yes the title of your question is misleading

Comment: By the way, are you aware that you set `dr` to two different values, one after the other?  Right inside your `if` statement.

Comment: Yes that's my error There is no column 2 @TimSchmelter

Comment: ok, sorry about that @Steve there are 11 columns

Comment: @AnnL. I was thinking that but I also tried calling just a DataRow without asigning it to a DataTable.NewRow(). Got same error.

Comment: Are you sure there is only one table in the DataSet returned by your method `Consulta`?

Comment: Yes, I think the page made a post back or something because when it entered the for cycle the DataRow goes null, I had to move the for cycle to the end so it would work, now it works, but it's still weird and as I said it worked fine for days until an hour ago @Steve

Comment: @Steve it actually returns a whole dataset (Consulta)